# Why my State is taking so long to update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect, use-state

I have used two APIs inside a useEffect. One is for params and when it returns the result. I am fetching the main API based on the array of data that I was received by first API for params and after that whatever final data I got from the main API I am setting it to the state called stocks.

The problem is that the state is not updating quickly its taking time of about 10seconds to update and I am not able to render the results because of that. I have checked using react Dev tools the state is updating after some time and I am getting the results from the API successfully.

Here is the code.

const Base = (props) => {

```
const [stocks,setStocks] = useState();



useEffect(()=>{
  const array = [];
    axios.get(`https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/nyse-other-listings/nyse-listed_json/data/e8ad01974d4110e790b227dc1541b193/nyse-listed_json.json`)
    .then(response => {


      response.data.slice(0,20).map(item =>{
        
         axios.get(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/metricsymbol=${item["ACT Symbol"]}&metric=all&token=process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN`)
            .then((response) =>{

              array.push(response)})
           
      })
           
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
   setStocks(array)
},[])


 return (
    <div>
    
    <div className="table_container">
         <table class="table">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col">COMPANY NAME</th>
             <th scope="col">SYMBOL</th> 
             <th scope="col">MARKET CAP</th>
             <th scope="col"> </th>
             <th scope="col">CURRENT PRICE</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
       
         {
          stocks !== undefined && stocks.length > 0? 
        
         stocks && stocks.map(item=>{
              return    <p>{JSON.stringify()}</p>  //here i am getting empty [] 
                       
             })
             :<h1>{JSON.stringify(stocks)}</h1>
             
             
         }
           
         </tbody>
       </table>
         </div>
    </div>

    
)
```

}

export default Base;

Comment: You appear to be making two network calls, one after the other. Depending on how fast those services are, you'll get lag on your end.

Comment: `setStocks(array)` will always be `setStocks([])`. _Then_ you will get the result of your async call, _then_ you will get the result of your 20 secondary async calls, provided the server doesn't block you for DDoS attack. Calls that will be made for nothing, because `setStocks([])` has already been called before even waiting for Axios. Also you are using `.map` without returning anything from it

Answer (score 1):

You are actually making a first API call, **then iterating over the response to make several external API calls**. This could only result to a long time operation, and it isn't related to a particular bug.

Best way to do it is to redesign API to return several values, or you should consider updating progressively the state while receiving responses.

Moreover, you should use `forEach` over `map` to iterate over data without needing the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above should be sufficient, however, I would also check if there is a parameter you could send in the request to limit the number of items returned in the response instead of slicing the array in the frontend. Because if the response returns a very large number of objects, it might cause an overall slower response time.

Comment: the response is giving over 3200 array of objects. how can i optimize it?

Comment: Well, usually the API provider should have some sort of interface that specifies what endpoints are available, and which parameters you can send with those requests, such as page/page size.